# ExecuterService's execute() method not executing sometimes even though when it's not shutdown or terminated - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

In my multi-threaded application, and in order to prevent *application not responding* (ANR), I used `ExecutorService` object's execute API to call the `startActvity()`. Most of the time it works as expected. I am able to see the logs `callIntent: starting` and `run: inside run`, but after I restart the device multiple time and try to call the `callIntent(context,intent)` it is not working sometimes. It's strange behavior.

What went wrong with this implementation?

> when I used the main/UI thread, I'm getting ANR and I already run
> HandlerThread to run this startActivity, but the same behavior

**executor is not shutdown nor terminated, but it failed to execute**

```java
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class App extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "##App##";
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        executorService= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public void callIntent(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.d(TAG, "callIntent: starting");
        if(executor.isShutdown()||executor.isTerminated()){
            Log.d(TAG, "callStartActivity executor is shutdown - restarting again ");
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "callStartActivity:not shut or trminated ");
        }
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: inside run ");
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Protips: Catch and log all exception in the `Runnable` that you pass on to an `ExcecutorService`, otherwise the thread can die silently and your `ExecutorService` will stop accepting new job.

Comment: no exception thrown here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason for this, but I used `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);` and I kept the thread count as 4, with no calculation for thread count 4, but it worked for me,

**anyone knows this reason please edit this answer and add the valid reason for this**

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "##App##";
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    }

    public void callIntent(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.d(TAG, "callIntent: starting");
        if(executor.isShutdown()||executor.isTerminated()){
            Log.d(TAG, "callStartActivity executor is shutdown - restarting again ");
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "callStartActivity:not shut or trminated ");
        }
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: inside run ");
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```